# How to properly do sliding on android?

Tags: android

ALL,
I have the following "simple" question. ;-)
I have an application which has an image background loaded from the png file.
On top I have an Image View which I would like to rotate with my fingers.
I am using MotionEvent to catch the sliding but apparently it works when I slide my fingers on the background but not on the image view.

My guess is that the view cover the background and the events are not ending up on the place.

How to overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the imageview to clickable and/or touchable.